# Ant WsImport throwing errors during compiling generated java files in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, ant, jaxb, wsimport

I am generating web service clients using gradle ant wsimport task and packaging the clients with **-clientJar option with -xnocompile set to false**.

During the compilation of generated Java code by xcompile option, its throwing an exception (**[ant:wsimport] compilation failed, errors should have been reported**) due to the dependencies **(Package abc.customDateAdapter does not exist)** on the generated java files are not resolved.

I am supplying a jaxb Global Binding file to wsimport task in which i have customized the xsd:date bindings with my customDateAdapter.
The package import of the customDateAdapter is not resolved on the generated Java files during ant wsimport.

The unresolved customDateAdapter package is in projectA which is compile time and buildscript classpath dependency for the current project.
But still the ant wsimport is not picking up the classpath dependency during compiling the generated java files.

Can someone please suggest how to add an external project as classpath dependency to ant wsimport  task.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue on my own.

Created the custom dependency configuration for ant wsImport and declared the required jars, with which the ant compilation works fine as expected.

Comment: can you please guide how to add custom dependency configuration for ant wsImport